# Tabbed menu in CSS and Javascript - tab sets to active after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tabbed menu written mainly in HTML and CSS. There are 5 tabs, the first one is set to active when we first load the page. I had to add little JS script, because that active tab wouldn't change its look to "not-active" when we clicked on another tab (so we had two tabs with "active" look). Everything works fine, but if we click on, let's say, 3rd tab and then refresh website, the first tab changes its look from "not-active" to "active", so there are two tabs with "active" look. Only the styling is wrong, content in the tabs views the right content... So if we click on another tab and refresh the page, we have two tabs with "active" look, but the website still views the content from the right tab. I don't want the first tab to set its look to "active" after refreshing page. I don't know JS and I don't know how to fix it.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function($){
       $(".tabmenu").children("div").click(function(){
           $(".current").removeClass("current");
       });
   });
```

Here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/y5SzQ/1/

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include jQuery (in your JSFiddle). Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5SzQ/2/) with jQuery included which seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution

```
$(".tabmenu").children("div").click(function () {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
})
.filter(location.hash).click();
```

<sub>(to test: change tab, right click Reload resule frame)</sub>

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y5SzQ/3/

What it does is just triggers click event similarly to what happens when user clicks with a mouse. If there is `location.hash` (say '#french-tab') and tab other then Polish has to be selected, then `.filter(location.hash)` will become for example `.filter('#french-tab')` and corresponding tab will be selected.

Comment: `.filter(location.hash).click();` is this making any sense? It is working even after you remove that code. Because what lacking there was the library

Comment: Read the question carefully, the problem is not that there was no jQuery. When you reload the page, last selected tab should be selected, **and** the first one (polish) unselected.